# Is there a way to customize the existing Contacts App available on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Is there a way to customize the existing Contacts App available on iPhone?

What I would require is a way to create an additional button in the Contacts App to do certain task. Is it possible to do it by means of a standard iPhone App?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn´t possible unless your phone is jailbroken. If you will try to modify the Contacts app by means of a standard iPhone app your app will get rejected in the review process.

If you still want to do it, you can use some private APIs, frameworks or libraries and distribute the app on Cydia.